# Variable assignment not working. Stdout to var

Tags: python, variables, stdout

I am trying to assign the stdout or the printed values to the variable byte. When the program is run it determines the value of a number rounds it to the nearest ones, tens, or hundreds place then removes the trailing zeros and prints a letter after it. For example if the number=920,193,032 the code will print 921m. I then need to store that output to a variable but I am not having any luck. I tried using the `from io import StringIO` method but all I got was a blank line.

```
div=#
divi=str(div)
divide=len(divi)
elif divide >= 7 and divide < 10:
    def roundup(x):
        return int(math.ceil(x / 1000000.0)) * 10**6
    z=roundup(div)
    array = [int(x) for x in str(z)]
    if divide == 7:
        byte=print(array[0], end="");print('m')
        
    elif divide == 8:
        byte=print(array[0], end="");print(array[1], end="");print('m')
        
    elif divide == 9:
        byte=print(array[0], end="");print(array[1], end="");print(array[2], end="");print('m')
```

Comment: The approach you show here will never work: output and returned value are different sorts of things; please edit your question and show your attempt with `StringIO`, so that we have a place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, don't use `print()`. (I do salute your creativity in even thinking of that, however!) Instead, just convert the value to a string.

```
byte=str(array[0]) +'m'
```

And so on for the others.

Python has a number of string formatting features that you could use. Here's the equivalent with an f-string, the newest string formatting feature:

```
bytes = f"{array[0]}m"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a way to format numbers as a string.  In this case, if `number=920,193,032`, then you could format this as `"{}m".format(int(number/1000000))` to get `921m`